# Is it possible to show/hide item based on another item's value in a ngFor?

Tags: angular

For example, I have a list like this:

```
items = [
  { key: "key0", value: "" },
  { key: "key1", value: "" },
  { key: "key2", value: "" },
  { key: "key3", value: "" },
  { key: "key4", value: "", dependency: "key2", dependency_value: "value2" },
  ...
]
```

The corresponding simple ngFor like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="item in items">
    <td>{{item.key}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to show/hide "key4" (i.e., item[4]) depending on whether "key2" (i.e., items[2].value) equals "value2" dynamically based on user's input. Is it possible?

Comment: *ngFor return a new item on each iteration, so based on prev iteration you can not put a check.
Better to use a separation function in the ts file, run a for loop and put a flag in items[4] object based on items[2] obj values.

Comment: Of course this is possible, just not with `*ngFor` . Do this logic in the TS file and add a property or something.. And then you use this in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<tr *ngFor="item in items; let i = index">
  <td *ngIf="
        i !== 4 ||
       (i === 4 && items[2].key === 'value2')
   ">
   {{item.key}}:
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**OR**

You can do this.

**.ts file**

```
filterData(items) {
  let newItems = [];
  let flag = false;
  for(let item in items){
     if(item.key == 'key2' && item.value == 'value2') {
        flag = true;
     }
     
     if(item.key != 'key4') {
        newItems.push(item);
     } else {
        if(!flag) newItems.push(item);
     }
  }
}
```

**.html file**

```
<tr *ngFor="item in newItems">
    <td>{{item.key}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)
If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
<tr *ngFor="item in items; let i = index">
   <td *ngIf=" i !== 4 ||  ( i === 4 && items[2].key === 'value2' )">
        {{item.key}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
   </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: The check should not be on the current iteration, it should be on the items[2] object key.

Comment: Okey, I guess I´m getting it now. The issue that I see is that you overwrite the item.value with ngModel, so you don´t have anything to compare the input with (?)

Comment: It's not about the ngModel.

While *ngFor runs, on each iteration you'll get items[0],items[1],items[2]...so how you gonna compare items[2] key on items[4] iteration. That will be gone right?

Comment: You can always make use of index parameter: `<tr *ngFor="item in items; let i = index"><td *ngIf=" i !== 4 ||  ( i === 4 && items[4] === items[2] )>{{item.key}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value"></td>
</tr>`

Comment: Okay, I got it now. `*ngIf=" i !== 4 ||  ( i === 4 && items[2].key === 'value2' )` will work in this case.

Comment: Please Accept/Upvote my answer if it resolved your issue or comment if you want me to edit it. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

It should works for your example:

```
<tr *ngFor="item in items; let i = index;">
   <ng-container *ngIf="i !== 4 || (i === 4 && items[2].value === item.dependency_value)">
      <td>
        {{item.key}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
      </td> 
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```